# What happen if I login another user without logout the previous user?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth to make Login feature for my app. As the title, I want to know what happen if I login another user without logout the previous user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't happen.  An app can only have one user signed in at a time while that app is running.  Signing in a new user necessarily removes the token for the old user, and only the new user's information will be available.

Comment: so, you meant the auth task will fail or the previous user "auto" logout to sign in the new user ?

Comment: The previous user will be logged out. Note that you can easily test this in your app, which probably answers most of the additional questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this once with one of my apps. The authentication of another user will fail unless the previous user signs out first.

Comment: yep, this is what I am thinking but not sure. thanks, now I get it

Answer (score 0):

> if I login another user without logout the previous user

if this happens then is your logout strategy correct? How would a new userB login without userA being logged out or userA session has expired? Perhaps a little more details would help here.

Let's say you are storing the current user using firebase then you can choose to delete the user manually to have a clean slate when next user login but this is not necessary as I think firebase already does this when new user logs in

Additional info on user management using firebase [can be found in their documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

Hope this helps

Comment: why do you delete the user ?